# splitting a string Python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any other way to do this:

```
>>> in_string = "Hello, world! how are you? Your oceans are pretty. Incomplete sentence"

>>> def sep_words(string_1):
"""Function which takes a string and returns a list of lists contining the words"""

        list_1 = string_1.split()
        list_output = []
        list_temp = []
    for i in list_1:
        if ((i[-1] == '!') or (i[-1] == '?') or (i[-1] == '.')):
            list_temp.append(i[:-1])
            list_temp.append(i[-1:])
            list_output.append(list_temp)
            list_temp = []
        else:
            list_temp.append(i)
    if list_temp == []:
        pass
    else:
        list_output.append(list_temp)
    print (list_output)


>>> sep_words(in_string)

[['Hello,', 'world', '!'], ['how', 'are', 'you', '?'], ['Your', 'oceans', 'are', 'pretty', '.'], ['Incomplete', 'sentence']]
```

Comment: So you want to split at space, `!`, `?` and `.`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```py
import re
message = "Hello, world! how are you? Your oceans are pretty. Incomplete sentence"
print re.findall(r"[A-Za-z,]+|\S", message)
```

Output:

```
['Hello,', 'world', '!', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?', 'Your', 'oceans', 'are', 'pretty', '.', 'Incomplete', 'sentence']
```

The expression looks for words containing one or more (`+`) letters and possibly a comma (`[A-Za-z,]`) or (`|`) a non-whitespace character (`\S`).